# URL parameters stripped on Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Using Google Apps Script gadget, I can use the parameters of the URL (`http://sites.google.com/.../my-page?urlparameter=value&otherurlparameter=value`) added to a Google Sites webpage to generate dynamic content.

But if you try to add a link to a page of a Google Site with parameters, and then save your page, the parameters are deleted : `http://sites.google.com/.../my-page?urlparameter=value&otherurlparameter=value` becomes `http://sites.google.com/.../my-page`. Same thing when trying to publish a webpage using Apps Script Service `SitesApp.Page.setHtmlContent(yourHmtl)`.

It doesn't happen when using external URLs.
How can we bypass this limitation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to include **relative** links to pages including parameters.

Example :
in `http://sites.google.com/.../home/page-1`, 
a link like `http://sites.google.com/.../home/page-2?urlparameters` will be overwritten without parameters but `../page-2?urlparameters` won't be.